# Angular 2: Dotar de valor a una variable desde una función y recogerlo en otra en la misma clase

Tags: angular

Necesito dotar a miVariable del valor indicado dentro de la funcion, donde recojo una data del servicio y mostrarla en otra función, pero desconozco la sintaxis.

```
export class clase{

  public this.miVariable:any;

  constructor(){}

  ngOnload():void{
    this.load()
   }

  load() {
         this.loadService.cargar().subscribe(
         (respuesta) => {
             this.carga = respuesta;
             this.miVariable=this.carga.mivalorRecogido; //necesito este valor
          }
         );
     }
   }

  otrafuncion(){
   console.log(this.miVariable);
  }

}
```

Comment: No se entiende en que parte tienes el problema, ¿a la hora de recoger el valor o a la hora de mostrarlo?. En cualquier caso, tu código parece correcto: si llamas a la funcion "otrafuncion()" una vez load() haya acabado y recibido la respuesta, te mostrará correctamente el valor de "miVariable" por consola. Eso sí, IMPORTANTE: te falta como minimo cargar el servicio de "loadService" en el constructor. constructor( private loadService: LoadService ) {} , y haces un import arriba del LoadService donde lo tengas.

Comment: Sí, Juan, tienes razón, falta el servicio ahí, olvidé colocarlo, muchas gracias.  Mi problema está en que cuando llame a la función otraFuncion desde un evento o así, pueda obtener el valor de miVariable ya modificado.